# Embed Jupyter Notebook editor in webapp

Tags: jupyter-notebook, codemirror, jupyterhub, jupyter-irkernel, jupyter-lab

Is there someone here to help me! 
I am working on a project in which my users must have their own space in oder to create, upload and run their notebook's script.I mean like I can do in my Jupyter notebook, I want give thema kind of code editor in which they will type or upload their code an I will run it in the background. I have seen that kaggle is doing soemthing like that and it seems they are using Jupyter?!
What I would like to know is that if I can come up with my problem with JupyterHub?
If yes can you give me more hints about it;;
If no, do you know, what kind of Techology can help me to achieve my goal?
Thank you

Comment: Please, do you have some source code to add into your request of help?

Comment: hello @alepuzio, thank you for your response. Unfortunatelly, I am starting from scratch and searching for technolgies or tools that can help me to achieve my goal!! I would like to to it using AngularJs web app so...

Comment: Did you achieve it?